# iPhone personal hotspot shows more connections than it should

Tags: tethering

I was using my Apple TV when I saw my iPhone showed more than one connection.

My iPad WiFi was closed and I had no other device that it can connect to.

I changed my password a few times. But my iPhone keeps flashing that there is a connection when it shouldn’t. It disappears and comes back within a few seconds.

Am I being hacked? Or is this some other issue?

Comment: Bluetooth can also tether if it is turned on. I don't have Apple TV so, do they have bluetooth? Even if not, just turn it off and check. Also, You might want to fix a probable typo in "*when seconds closed my*" by [edit] button.